How to assign complex objects to context in React?
I am trying to set data of context.
context :
import React from "react";
const AppContext = React.createContext<IContext>({} as IContext);
export default AppContext;

In App.tsx file I fill with default values :
function App() {

    const [ContextData, setContextData] = useState({
        profile: {
            firstName: "",
            lastName: ""
        },
        package: {
            name:"",
            code: "",
            version: "",
            totalPumpCount: 0
        }
    });

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ ContextData, setContextData }}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
                    <Route path="/DailyWorkPlan" element={<DailyWorkPlan />} />
                    <Route path="/Setting" element={<Setting />} />
                    <Route path="/Report" element={<Report />} />
                    <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
                    <Route path="/PumpsStatus" element={<PumpsStatus />} />
                    <Route path="/SensorsStatus" element={<SensorsStatus />} />
                    <Route path="/PackageCommands" element={<PackageCommands />} />
                    <Route path="/PumpsService" element={<PumpsService />} />
                    <Route path="/DrivesService" element={<DrivesService />} />
                    <Route path="/DailyFlow" element={<DailyFlow />} />
                    <Route path="/DataBase" element={<DataBase />} />
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default App;

and then in another component, I try to fetch data and set it to context :
 const { ContextData, setContextData } = React.useContext(AppContext);
 //fill user context
 useMount(() => {

    fetch('/home/GetContext')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            setContextData({
                profile: {
                    firstName: response.data?.firstName,
                    lastName: response.data?.lastName,
                    id: 0,
                    userId: '',
                    mobile: '',
                    allowSendSmsOnOff: false,
                    allowSendSmsFault: false,
                    allowSendSmsSensor: false,
                    allowSendSmsDriveConnection: false,
                    allowSendSmsLoginFailed: false,
                    isActive: false
                },
                package: {
                    totalPumpCount: response.data?.totalPumpCount,
                    name: response.data?.name,
                    code: response.data?.code,
                    version: response.data?.version,
                }

            });



        }).then(() => {
            console.log(ContextData);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            toast.error('/home/GetContext : ' + error.message);
        });
});
    


interface IContext {
    profile: IProfile,
    package: IPackage,
    setContextData(arg0: IContext): IContext
}

The fetched data is not set currently!!!
What is the problem?

console.log(ContextData); is logging the state captured from the previous render, not the state that you just set

I checked it in another section but the context is free !!!

That's still capturing the same render's state. If you were to instead console.log(ContextData); at the top level of that component, you'd see the initial state, then the updated state.

I log Context in the destination component but it is still free.

How are you doing that logging? If you are doing it in useMount, then it will always show you the initial empty context. If you do it in useEffect(()=> console.log(ContextData), [ContextData]);, there should be two logs, first with the empty context, and second with the filled context

The shape of your IContextData does not match what you provide with value={{ ContextData, setContextData }}.
You'd want value={{ ...ContextData, setContextData }} to destructure the state atom (profile, package) into the context value.
